# Loading images with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I've a ul li menu such like:

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#1">Image #1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#2">Image #2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#3">Image #3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#4">Image #4</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I have a container with an image like:

```
<div id="image-container">
     <img src="images/1.jpg">
</div>
```

I want to switch the image in "image-container" div using "hash" and "load" (every image is in /image/ folder and each is named like hashes, so  loads images/2.jpg etc.

I'm trying this way:

```
$("#ul li:nth-child(1)").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();   
        var hash = this.parentNode.hash;  
        $("#image-container").load('images/'+ hash.substring(1) +'.jpg');

$("#ul li:nth-child(2)").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();   
        var hash = this.parentNode.hash;  
        $("#image-container").load('images/'+ hash.substring(1) +'.jpg');

$("#ul li:nth-child(3)").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();   
        var hash = this.parentNode.hash;  
        $("#image-container").load('images/'+ hash.substring(1) +'.jpg');

(...)
```

But it doesn't work so well (I guess I'm going to need something slightly different than load, because it won't change my image anyways?).

Thanks a lot.

And by the way - is there a way to write my jQuery code shorter (in one function, because now I have multiple with the same body)?

Thanks a lot,
Ada :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your code a bit shorter like this:

```
$("ul li a").click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();   
  $("#image-container img").attr('src', 'images/'+ this.hash.substring(1) +'.jpg');
});
```

[You can try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/s6FXy/), a few changes from your original:

- Attach the handler to the `<a>`, it has the hash
- You can bind the same handler to many elements, just use a selector that grabs all the element you want
- Get the has from `this` since `this` refers to the `<a>` element
- You `<ul>` doesn't have a `id="ul"` attribute, so the selector should be `ul`, not `#ul`
- Don't use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which is for fetching content, instead set the `src` if the `<img>` using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).